# How to access a public certificate in a node.js azure function

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, azure-functions

I've imported a public certificate to my azure function through

> My Azure function app service -> Platform Features tab -> SSL ->
>   Public Key Certificates (.cer)

Now how do I access this through my azure function?

I've tried researching this but the only [results I can find are for using a private certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327847/use-ssl-certificate-in-azure-function-app-with-nodejs)

Currently to get around this I am telling node to ignore the self signed certificate for the endpoint I am integrating with by setting `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';`

I would like to use the certificate instead.

**Edit:**

I ended up adding the certificate chain to a folder and reading the files from the folder in my application. Still doesn't answer the question on how to use the azure uploaded certificate though

```
const https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.ca = [
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/master.pem'),
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/root.pem')
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue with the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#make-the-certificate-accessible) and they updated it to say you can only load SSL certs stored in azure with c#

If you're not using c# you have to store the ssl cert in a folder with your code and read it from the file as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the certificate uploaded on the TLS/SSL settings by configuring the app settings WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with the value of the certificate thumbprint.

the below is the code where you can fetch the certificate in a programmatic manner using node.js (with npm package 'win-ca').

```
const http = require('http');
const ca = require('win-ca');

// Create an instance of the http server to handle HTTP requests
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {

// Set a response type of plain text for the response
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

// certificate fetch 
let certificates = []

// Fetch all certificates in PEM format from My store
ca({
    format: ca.der2.pem,
    store: ['My'],
    ondata: crt => certificates.push(crt)
})

// Send back a response and end the connection
  res.end("Certificate count under 'My' store is" + certificates.length);
});

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(port);

console.log('Node server running on port ' + port);
```

You can change the store parameter to which you want the certificate from ex: Root, My, CertificationAuthority, AuthRoot.